# Extracting values from Yaml file using Bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, azure-devops, grep, cut

I have yaml file and it is located in a different directory.
Chart.yaml:

```
apiversion:v2
name: microservicename
version: 1.0.0
appVersion: "1.2.1"
```

I want extract value and save it in variable. The output in variable should be :1.2.1

Can you suggest me how to use grep, awk, sed in this scenario?

I have tried using yq , it doesn't work.

installing yq , neit

expecting output in a variable =1.2.1

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Please edit your question and post valid YAML.

Answer (score 2):

Valid YAML keys & values are separated by a colon and a space.
The example you provided does not have a space between the colon on the first line.

This is valid:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: microservicename
version: 1.0.0
appVersion: "1.2.1"
```

You could then use yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```
yq e '.appVersion' <path_to_your_yaml_file>
```

In case you use yq from https://pypi.org/project/yq/ this should do the trick:

```
yq .appVersion <path_to_your_yaml_file>
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU AWK

```
awk -F'"' '/appVersion/{print $2}' /path/to/Chart.yaml
```

1. `-F'"'` using `"` as delimiter
2. `/appVersion/` looking for the "appVersion" line
3. `print $2` printing second field

---

OR

```
awk '/appVersion/{gsub(/"/,""); print $2}' /path/to/Chart.yaml
```

1. using default delimiter `blank`
2. `/appVersion/` looking for the "appVersion" line
3. `gsub(/"/,"")` deleting all `"`
4. `print $2` printing second field

---

```
$ myvar=$(awk -F'"' '/appVersion/{print $2}' /path/to/Chart.yaml) 
$ echo $myvar
1.2.1
$ myvar=$(awk '/appVersion/{gsub(/"/,""); print $2}' /path/to/Chart.yaml)
$ echo $myvar
1.2.1
```

Comment: Can you add some comments to what you've done here?